# inserting count down Index into a field

Tags: t-sql

I have data like this

```
   ParentId          Start_date            CompName
   ==================================================
      1                 20/03/2023           Comp1
      1                 10/01/2023           Comp2 
      1                 16/08/2023           Comp3
      1                 11/11/2023           Comp4
```

I want select these records and insert into another table with extra field(IndexF), the data for the extra field would be calculated like this :

1. Maximum Start_Date(11/11/2023) has IndexF zero
2. the Row with 16/08/2023 Start_Date has IndexF 85
3. the Row with 20/03/2023  Start_Date has IndexF 84
4. the Row with 10/01/2023  Start_Date has IndexF 83

is there any way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

We can use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` with the help of `ROW_NUMBER` and a `CASE` expression:

```sql
INSERT INTO OtherTable (ParentId, Start_date, CompName, IndexF)
SELECT ParentId, Start_date, CompName,
       CASE WHEN Start_date = MAX(Start_date) OVER ()
            THEN 0
            ELSE 87 - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Start_date DESC) END
FROM yourTable;
```